# Check if max_execution_time and memory_limit is set to desired values

Tags: php

I have following php function

```
function allocate_resources()
{
    ini_set('max_execution_time',2700); //set maximum execution time of script
    ini_set('memory_limit','1024M'); //set memory_limit for script
}
```

This function is called in many functions to allocate resources, so I want to check

if **max_execution_time** is not set ot **2700** then set it to **2700**

if **memory_limit** is not set ot **1024M** then set it to **1024M**

Any better solution is also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$max_time = ini_get("max_execution_time");
$memory_limit = ini_get('memory_limit');
```

to get `max_execution_time` & `memory_limit`. And using `if` check whether those values are set, if not apply yours.

Getting `memory_limit`:

```
$memory_limit = ini_get('memory_limit');
if (preg_match('/^(\d+)(.)$/', $memory_limit, $matches)) {
    if ($matches[2] == 'M') {
        $memory_limit = $matches[1] * 1024 * 1024; // nnnM -> nnn MB
    } else if ($matches[2] == 'K') {
        $memory_limit = $matches[1] * 1024; // nnnK -> nnn KB
    }
}
```

**It should be noted that** `ini_set('max_execution_time', 2700);` and `set_time_limit(2700);` are not completely synonymous, because `set_time_limit()` "resets" the counter to 0, which `ini_set()` does not.

Comment: thank you @Sinto, how to check `if ( ini_get("memory_limit") < 1024M )`  and avoid `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'M'`

Comment: Values in my function are hard-coded, should I use like this for efficiency `if ( ini_get("memory_limit") < 1048576 )
{
       ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
}`

Comment: Ya, you can use it directly

Answer (score 0):

Use **ini_get()**

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>
> Gets the value of a configuration option

e.g. `$max_exec_time = ini_get('max_execution_time');`